# Tool for converting .shp file to .tab file?

Tags: shapefile, mapinfo, convert

I am searching for any free tool which can convert ShapeFile (.shp) to MapInfo (.tab) file.

Comment: I think you want to export shape file (.shp) to Map infor (.tab) format is that correct ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have MapInfo you can use the [Universal Translator](https://web.archive.org/web/20160222091552/http://reference.mapinfo.com:80/software/mapinfo_pro/english/9.0/UT_UG.pdf), or you could use:

[ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)

[FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/windows-main.html)

Answer (score 10):

ogr2ogr is good. If you prefer a GUI you can use ogr2gui from http://www.ogr2gui.ca/en/index.php

Comment: +1 for the GUI reference.  Thanks for contributing and welcome to our site!

Answer (score 3):

If your really keen and like to try different software. Then you can get a 14day trial of FME from Safe software which is actually quite an interesting piece of software.

Answer (score 3):

.shx files are the index files for Shapefiles (.shp)
Shapefiles consist of 3 files:

1. .shp file
2. .shx file
3. .dbf file

Simply exporting one of these files will **not** export the data. Thats a crude way of doing things.

Having said that, .SHP cannot be directly exported to non-ArcGIS format. You will need a tool like Data Interoperability to export from ArcGIS. Yes, if you have access to MapInfo, you can directly read Shapefiles (as .shp is an "open" format) and save it as TAB files!