# How to convert ArcMap *.shp to MapInfo *.tab file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, mapinfo, export, tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool for converting .shp file to .tab file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11667/tool-for-converting-shp-file-to-tab-file)

I have files in ArcGIS format, I want to export some layers to Mapinfo files as tab file